# Annotating Coq proofs

Tags: coq

I am a beginner Coq user.

While it is satisfying that the computer verified the proof for me, proofs that satisfy Coq are notoriously difficult to read for humans. Here is a simple example, imagine you don't see any of the comments:

```
Theorem add_comm : forall n m : nat,
  n + m = m + n.
Proof.
  intros n m.
  induction m as [|m Hm].
  -                        (*     n + 0 = 0 + n       *)
    simpl.                 (*     n + 0 = n           *)
    apply add_0_r.         (*                         *)
  -                        (*   n + S m = S m + n     *)
    simpl.                 (*   n + S m = S (m + n)   *)
    rewrite <- Hm.         (*   n + S m = S (n + m)   *)
    rewrite <- plus_n_Sm.  (* S (n + m) = S (n + m)   *)
    reflexivity.           (*                         *)
  Qed.
```

I honestly cannot read the proof without the comments, even less so if I want to show it to audiences who don't know about Coq.

Writing these comments manually is tedious, and Coq generates them anyway. I wonder if Coq can simply automatically annotate my proof so to make it more readable?

Answer (score 3):

It's not literally what you asked for, as it doesn't add text to the .v file itself (afaik), but [Alectryon](https://github.com/cpitclaudel/alectryon) allows you to generate documentation where the goal state appears when you hover the mouse on top of a tactic. See [here](https://alectryon-paper.github.io/) for several examples.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution to annotating the proof is to replay it, by opening the file and stepping through it to see the intermediate goals. I think even experts often do this to understand a proof, and many Coq demos also resort to this to go over proofs. Depending on your setting and goals, this might be simpler than setting Alectryon up.